How can I change color of ElevatedButton to press it?
I want to change button color from lightblue to green, and text.
I could change text, but I couldn't change color. I couldn't resolve it yet.
I want to use 'setState()' in 'onPressed()' to change color when I press the button.
If I used styleFrom, can I use styleFrom in setState to change color??
How can I fix it?
There is source code for it.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: const MyStatefulWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  String frontText = "Press the Button to see studuent infomation";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { // Defining Main Widget plqcing on Scaffold
    final ButtonStyle style = ElevatedButton.styleFrom();

    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "$frontText", key: Key("textKey"),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 15),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom( // Setting the ElevatedButton style
                backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue[50],
                foregroundColor: Colors.blue,
                textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)
            ),
            child: const Text('Push'),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() { // once push the button, text printed over the button will be changed
                frontText = "20190952, 윤영준";
                ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.green
                ); // I want change color to green, but i can't
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

enter image description here

You have few issues:
style is defined, but value it's never used. In addition you must make it a field instead of a property inside the build method.
ButtonStyle style = ElevatedButton.styleFrom();

You must use the style property instead of creating a new one.
ElevatedButton(
    style: style,
    ...
),

And last but not least - ElevatedButton.styleFrom does nothing, you have to rewrite the style value to apply the new changes.
setState(() {
   ...
   style = ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.green);
   // or if you want to preserve other configurations
   // style = style.copyWith(...);
});

p.s. That's how I would do it:
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool pressed = false;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            pressed ? "20190952, 윤영준" : "Press the Button to see studuent infomation",
            key: Key("textKey"),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 15),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom( // Setting the ElevatedButton style
                backgroundColor: pressed ? Colors.green : Colors.lightBlue[50],
                foregroundColor: Colors.blue,
                textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)
            ),
            child: const Text('Push'),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                pressed = true;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

